# The abc conjecture and the existence of finite number of solutions for the Beal's problem

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

In this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal%27s_conjecture#cite_ref-9), I am not interested on the Beal conjecture itself. But I am interested on the following problem:

> The author claimed:
>
> **The  [abc conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture) would imply that there are at most finitely many counterexamples to Beal's conjecture.**

My **question** is: Is there are a proof for this claim.

Comment: Really?  How about start with the statement of Beal's conjecture and abc conjecture.  Do you not see an obvious choice for a, b and c?

Comment: @ErickWong: Yes, but I cannot continue with this.

Comment: You wrote "I have no idea to start".

Comment: @ErickWong: Yes removed.

Comment: Can you please explain where you get stuck?  Do you understand the statement of abc?  For instance, it is pretty clear that $\text{rad}(A^x B^y C^z) \le ABC$.

Comment: @ErickWong: If the abc conjecture is true then there exist a finite number of solutions for the Beal's problem.

Comment: Yes, there is a proof for this claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, for any positive $\epsilon < 1/12$ the inequality given in the $abc$-conjecture
$$
rad(abc) > c_{\epsilon}c^{1-\epsilon}
$$
with an explicit value of $c_{\epsilon}>0$ yields
an explicit upper bound on $x^p, y^q, z^r$ in any counterexample to Beal's conjecture. By the $abc$-conjecture, there are only finitely many such $(a,b,c)$-triples.